# Does setting the checked attribute on a radio button change the checked attributed on other buttons with the same name?

Tags: javascript

If I have a group of radion buttons, with one being set as checked by default:

```
<input type="radio" id="id1" name="grp" value="val1" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" id="id2" name="grp" value="val2">
<input type="radio" id="id3" name="grp" value="val3">
```

If I now get the element with ID "id2" and do

```
var el = ...;
el.checked = true;
```

will the `checked` property for the other elements automatically be set to `false`?

Bonus points for a link to official documentation describing the behavior.

Comment: may be not. by JavaScript it may not affecting automatically to other elements. you may have to write JavaScript for that also..I am not sure for that, but may be i m right..Thanks.

Comment: @Chandresh: You're incorrect. Let's not speculate, let's look at documentation (and empirical results).

Comment: @Chandresh: Apologies, there was *meant* to be a smile after my comment above. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does setting the checked attribute on a radio button change the checked attributed on other buttons with the same name?

Yes, it does. I'm surprised to find that this behavior isn't clearly documented in the [DOM2 HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-30233917). It is, though, documented in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#radio-button-state) and the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#radio).

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/umava3)

Comment: Fixed the incorrect markup. It was a cut-n-paste error. My original markup is a valid `input` tag.

Comment: @tibbe: I figured it was something like that. :-) (I removed that part of the answer.) Glad that helped!